# Can the limits be applied differently to the following multiple integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

The question is to change the cartesian form to the corresponding polar form:
$$\int_0^a\int_y^a{\frac{x^2\,dx\,dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$$
The limit when applied in the format
$\theta =0$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$
and $r=a$ and $r=a\sec(\theta)$
The integral evaluates to $$I=\frac{a^3}{3}\log(1+\sqrt{2})$$

But when the radius limit is changed to $r=a$ and $r=a\sqrt{2}$

the integral evaluates to 
$$I=\frac{a^3\pi}{24}(2\sqrt{2}-1)$$
is the answer same as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check on a calculator, using $a=1$, shows your expressions for $I$ are different. The first gives the value $0.293791$ while the second gives the value $0.239341$. The first one is correct, the second is wrong. The first is also equivalent to $\frac 13\operatorname{sinh}^{-1}(1)$, by the way.

You do not give details on how you found your answers, but I do see that your stated limits on $r$ are wrong. Here is the region of integration:

[image]

The limits on $r$ should be $0\le r\le a\sec\theta$, but you stated $a\le r\le a\sec\theta$ the first time and $a\le r\le a\sqrt 2$ the second time. Both statements are wrong. Your limits on theta, $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}4$, are correct. As I said, your first value is correct.

Comment: I think, I realised the mistake. I just took the radius at the end position directly, But $a\sec(\theta)$ gives the variation of the radius which is not in a circular manner but following the vertical line.